# Utilizar el codigo *ngIf en ionic

Tags: html, ionic, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]intento poner *ngIf en ionic pero no me desglosa ningun atajo ni mucho menos, como lo podría hacer :c.

Cuando lo pongo en la page.ts si me deja pero en el html no :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El *ngIf en Ionic, al ser programado usando Angular, es una directiva, por lo que debes usarlo como un atributo de una etiqueta. Por ejemplo:

```
<div *ngIf="true"></div>
```